# apache spark, "failed to create any local dir"

Tags: python, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am trying to setup Apache-Spark on a small standalone cluster (1 Master Node and 8 Slave Nodes).  I have installed the "pre-built" version of spark 1.1.0 built on top of Hadoop 2.4.  I have set up the passwordless ssh between nodes and exported a few necessary environment variables.  One of these variables (which is probably most relevant) is:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/scratch/spark/
```

I have a small piece of python code which I know works with Spark.  I can run it locally--on my desktop, not the cluster--with:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit ~/My_code.py
```

I copied the code to the cluster.  Then, I start all the processes from the head node:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all
```

And each of the slaves is listed as running as process xxxxx.

If I then attempt to run my code with the same command above:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit ~/MY_code.py
```

I get the following error:

```
14/10/27 14:19:02 ERROR util.Utils: Failed to create local root dir in /scratch/spark/.  Ignoring this directory.
14/10/27 14:19:02 ERROR storage.DiskBlockManager: Failed to create any local dir.
```

I have the permissions set on the `/scratch` and `/scratch/spark` at 777.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't realize the master node also needed a scratch directory.  In each of my 8 worker nodes I created the local /scratch/spark directory, but neglected to do so on the master node.  Adding the directory fixed the problem.

Comment: I also have a similar problem, I have an Ambari setup, Can you let me know how to identify which is a master node?