# Apache PySpark lost executor - Failed to create local dir

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to perform a .leftOuterJoin in pyspark. I'm using EC2, Anaconda, iPython notebook, interactive mode and Spark 1.3.0.

When I run the following code:

```
success_rdd = keyedtrips_rdd.leftOuterJoin(success_rdd)
success_rdd = success_rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
some_successes = success_rdd.take(100)
```

Spark gets about half-way through the process and then fails with the following message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1361 in stage 16.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1361.3 in stage 16.0 (TID 10438, ip-172-31-43-119.eu-west-1.compute.internal): java.io.IOException: Failed to create local dir in /mnt2/spark/spark-58043a43-5bfc-4610-a6bf-faae43b5ea5d/spark-c31061af-7fc0-45ab-b2ab-8f008005451d/spark-2ca18976-6219-4965-ac3b-aecf2e098cc1/blockmgr-40100c28-6c13-41c9-8617-9dfcf187040c/05.
```

Really appreciate any help, I'm quite stumped by this. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594312/apache-spark-failed-to-create-any-local-dir/) may talk about the same issue, but I don't understand the response. I've run leftOuterJoin's in the past and never seen this error before...

Comment: Hi @user3279453, were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem and I have both master and executor on the same node. After a few successful runs, this fails stating the same error as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your master's `SparkConf` you define `spark.local.dir` to a local writable directory.  It has to be writable by the user you are running spark as.

[image: SparfConf]

More information can be found here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: I see the same error; I have not set `spark.local.dir` so I believe it should still be the default (`/tmp`), which is writable by the user that is running Spark.  In other words, I don't think it's a permissions problem.