# Apache Spark Failed to create Temp Directory

Tags: apache-spark

I am a newbie to Apache-Spark and trying to create SparkConf from my application (tomcat) and I notice the below error

```
ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DiskBlockManager.logError(91) | Failed to create local dir in /opt/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/temp. Ignoring this directory.
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp directory (under /opt/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/temp) after 10 attempts!
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createDirectory(Utils.scala:285)
```

I haven't configured **SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS** in spark-env.sh. It's commented out as per default installation.

I think my issue is related to [apache spark, “failed to create any local dir”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594312/apache-spark-failed-to-create-any-local-dir) but not very sure. Should I configure SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS to a valid directory in each of master/worker nodes ? If so what's the minimum disk space that directory must have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *I haven't configured SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in spark-env.sh. It's commented
  out as per default installation.*

  If you don't configure,then it would take default location **/temp**
- *Should I configure SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS to a valid directory in each of
  master/worker nodes ?*
  Yes.its better to configure to a location where you have decent amount space that your application might require.
- *If so what's the minimum disk space that directory must have ?*

Depends on your application size, number of jobs you expected to be run, amount of logs each worker generates, amount of data you going to handle (intermediate shuffling data would be stored here), number of cache and volume of data you are about to cache and so on.
I'm configuring decent 100+GB space in my application and its certainly depends on the parameters just I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem as follows.

1. You can create SparkConfWithEnv class and extend SparkConf.

   ```
   import java.util.Map;
   import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
   import scala.Tuple2;
   public class SparkConfWithEnv extends SparkConf {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       private Map<String, String> env = null;

       public SparkConfWithEnv(Map<String, String> env) {
           this.env = env;
       }

       public String getenv(String name) {
           String val = env.get(name);
           if (val == null) {
               return super.getenv(name);
           }
           return val;
       }

       public SparkConf clone() {
           SparkConf conf = new SparkConfWithEnv(env);
           Tuple2<String, String>[] all = getAll();
           for (Tuple2<String, String> tuple2 : all) {
               conf.set(tuple2._1, tuple2._2);
           }
           return conf;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` at init class:

   ```
   static SparkConf conf=null;
   static SparkContext sc = null;

   static {
       Map<String,String> map=Maps.newHashMap();
       map.put("SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS", "/opt/tars/apps/spark");
       conf=new SparkConfWithEnv(map).setMaster("local").setAppName(appId);
       sc = new SparkContext(conf);
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem.
If memory is full, get this error, look for the space available on the node 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No space left on device

Cleared memory and able to execute the jobs.